# Calculating components of waterfall chart weighted

Tags: math, statistics

I'm looking to create a waterfall chart for a business presentation to look at the difference in spend per customer across three segments year-over-year:

- Low value guests
- Medium value guests
- High value guests

Here's my dataset:

**2022 Spend per Customer** (weighted spend per customer = $340):

| Segment | Number of customers | **Spend per Customer** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Low value customers | 5200 | $150 |
| Medium value customers | 8500 | $262 |
| High value customers | 10,300 | $500 |

**2023 Spend per Customer** (weighted spend per customer = $420)

| Segment | Number of customers | Spend per Customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Low value customers | 2000 | $125 |
| Medium value customers | 1500 | $280 |
| High value customers | 4200 | $610 |

I want to build waterfall chart components that measures the impact in the change of weight of customers and spend per customer YoY. The differences of the three components should add up to $80.

I've tried simply copy/pasting each component of 2023 to 2022, but I don't think that's an accurate way of measuring.

I've tried just copy/pasting each row from 2023 to 2022 and re-calculating the weighted average, but don't think that's accurate.